# Dragging the screen to scroll

Tags: javascript, frontend, dom-events, web-frontend

I am trying to drag the screen with mouse horizontally/vertically. I am able to achieve horizontal dragging with the help of this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9EWifQ5xqA.

I tried the similar logic for vertical direction as well but somehow it is not working. Can someone please  give some insights on what could be wrong? Or can share any other way to drag the screen vertically with mouse?
This is the code logic I am using:

```
const container = document.querySelector('#inventory');

    let startY;
    let startX;
    let scrollLeft;
    let scrollTop;
    let isDown;

    container.addEventListener('mousedown',e => mouseIsDown(e));  
    container.addEventListener('mouseup',e => mouseUp(e))
    container.addEventListener('mouseleave',e=>mouseLeave(e));
    container.addEventListener('mousemove',e=>mouseMove(e));

    function mouseIsDown(e){
    isDown = true;
    startY = e.pageY - container.offsetTop;
    startX = e.pageX - container.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = container.scrollLeft;
    scrollTop = container.scrollTop; 
    }
    function mouseUp(e){
    isDown = false;
    }
    function mouseLeave(e){
    isDown = false;
    }
    function mouseMove(e){
    if(isDown){
        e.preventDefault();
        //Move vertcally
        const y = e.pageY - container.offsetTop;
        const walkY = y - startY;
        container.scrollTop = scrollTop - walkY;

        //Move Horizontally
        const x = e.pageX - container.offsetLeft;
        const walkX = x - startX;
        container.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walkX;

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [panzoom](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom) in the past and pleasantly surprised with it. I would recommend using such a library rather than hand coding it. It has easing which enhances the user experience.